# Bgslibrary Cmake failed with pip

Tags: python, c++, opencv, cmake

I would like to install bgslibrary for my project.
I also downloaded and extracted opencv, placed variable in PATH (win10)

But when i run:
`pip install pybgs`

I get this error:

```
Found package configuration file:

        C:/Users/USER/Downloads/opencv/build/OpenCVConfig.cmake

      but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be
      NOT FOUND.
```

I would like to use it in python, and the guide also say it is working.
https://github.com/andrewssobral/bgslibrary/wiki/Wrapper:-Python

Comment: I dont use visual studio.

Comment: *"downloaded and extracted opencv"* - This is different than installing. Did you follow the steps to build and install openCV on your system?

Comment: I'm not sure which version of OpenCV you are using, but if you haven't done so already, try one of the OpenCV installation tutorials. [This](https://cv-tricks.com/how-to/installation-of-opencv-4-1-0-in-windows-10-from-source/) one looks fairly comprehensive.

Comment: What do you mean? I already have a version installed by pip (pip install opencv-python ).

Comment: I use latest from everything.

Comment: "... placed variable in PATH" - What **exact** path have you added to the PATH variable? Is it `C:/Users/USER/Downloads/opencv/build/`?

Comment: Yes. Double checked.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

*I used Cmake-GUI.*

**Set the opencv-build location.**

**I had to use vs17-x64!!**